# File upload input in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have been trying to make a file upload for my spring boot project. I am currently following this tutorial from Baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload

However, I reached some problems. I have put this within my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and this within my application.properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=128KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=128KB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.location=${java.io.tmpdir}
```

for my project, I only need uploading a file so I put this as my form in `rekonsiliasi.html`

```
<form method="POST" action="/spring-mvc-xml/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="file">Select a file to upload</form:label></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<h2>Submitted File</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>OriginalFileName:</td>
        <td>${file.originalFilename}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Type:</td>
        <td>${file.contentType}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I add this into my `RekonsiliasiController`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.addAttribute("file", file);
    return "rekonsiliasi";
}
```

However, when I run it I leads me into 405 error with the message as following.

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

I tried to look it up on how to fix this and I found this: [Why SpringMVC Request method 'GET' not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333611/why-springmvc-request-method-get-not-supported)

So I tried to change all POST into GET and I received 500 error with this as the message

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The request to the `/uploadFile` endpoint must be a POST

Comment: @GiancarloRomeo I have tried to keep request method as POST within my rekonsiliasiController file and within my HTML but it gives me an error that said `org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported`

Comment: This exception means that you are sending a `GET`, not a `POST`

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request

Comment: @Gagak please refer, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3333611/8700934

Comment: @Lakshan I have tried that solution and it doesn't work

Comment: @Gagak How are you making the http request to the `uploadFile` endpoint?

Comment: @Gagak please refer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324734/8700934